# ActiveCell.End gives "Invalid use of property" error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a code that stores the first and last values of an array into different variables. I first select the first value of an array and then try go to the end of the range with "ActiveCell.End (xlDown)" command. This results in a "Invalid use of property" error right at the start of the sub.

```
Option Explicit
    Dim alku_norm1 As Range
    Dim loppu_norm1 As Range

Sub my_sub()
    Range("A11").Select
    Set alku_norm1 = Selection
    ActiveCell.End (xlDown)
    Set loppu_norm1 = Selection
End sub
```

Comment: You're mising `.Select` on the end of that line, although all that selecting is generally completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim alku_norm1 As Range
Dim loppu_norm1 As Range

Sub my_sub()
    Set alku_norm1 = Range("A1")
    Set loppu_norm1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
End Sub
```

Comment: To avoid problems when for example `A11` is already the last cell, you should always go vice versa: `Cells(rows.Count, "A").end(xlUp)`.

Comment: @FunThomas "always" is a dangerous word. ;)

Comment: @Rory: Sure. Obligatory link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba